# Using fread with grep on only one column

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to read only part of a very large .csv file into R. The data look like:

```
id   var1
111  A345
112  110
113  456
```

I would like only rows that start with "11" in `var1`. But this gives all rows in this example:

```
fread(cmd = paste('grep', '"^11"', 'mycsv.csv'), colClasses = c("integer", "character"))
```

I think gawk/awk would work with something like `$2~^11`, but I'm on a remote machine that I can't install on, and it doesn't seem to be able to call either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get creative you can try something like this:

```
#' @param file path to file.
#' @param sep delimiter for file.
#' @param pattern extended regular expression.
#' @param column_indx number index of column to apply pattern on.
#' @param ... additional arguments to pass to fread
fread_grep_column <- function(file, sep, pattern, column_indx, ...){
  cmd <- paste0("grep -E ", "'^", paste(c(rep("(.*)", column_indx-1), pattern), collapse = sep), "' ", file)
  cat(cmd, "\n") #just for debugging
  fread(cmd = cmd, ...)
}
```

This function will try and create a regular expression that will match your pattern on the correct row.

Although this will probably only work best with files that you are intimately familiar with. For example, you would need to know if the column you are grepping starts with quotes. I'm sure there are other ways this function could break, I just haven't thought of any good examples yet.

One thing to keep in mind - it will grep first and then read in the resulting file. In other words, if you headers do not exist in the pattern than you might want to add on the the function to fix that.